# Detecting movement using phones

Tags: security, mobile, packet-sniffers

I'd like to uniquely identify all wireless devices (phones, tablets, etc) within range. I don't care how far the devices are nor do I need to send them anything. I just want to be able to say: phone ABC was in this zone between 9:00 - 9:30, and 17:00 - 18:00.

I was thinking of [sniffing Wifi packets](https://superuser.com/questions/128166/is-looking-for-wi-fi-access-points-purely-passive/128200#128200) but it seems that [some phones](http://blog.taddong.com/2011/05/vulnerability-in-android-to-add-or-not.html) avoid sending Probe Request packets, furthermore it's difficult to get Wifi cards into [Monitor Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode). I've been unable to find any information on EDGE/3G detection.

I'm trying to measure queuing time similar to what they do in [Finland](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/07/20/2152246/Airport-Queuing-Time-Measured-With-Bluetooth).

The approach must "uniquely identify" the device. Meaning I want to be able to differentiate between the same device entering the zone multiple times versus new devices entering.

The approach must collect "anonymous" data, meaning I don't want to record any information that would allow someone to figure out the owner's identity.

**What's the best way to detect the presence of mobile devices**?

Comment: If you give a small indication of a legitimate reason for this, you might get better responses. Otherwise, this just seems like hackery.

Comment: I'd like to know what options people have when doing this so I don't get caught unaware.

Comment: It's not as simple as purchasing a USB 3G modem and hacking the software.  Uplink and downlink are on different frequencies, so you won't be able to detect the transmissions of other phones.  And even if you could infer it from the downlink (i.e. the basestation's transmissions), everything's encrypted apart from the broadcast channels.  Also, note that a phone "entering or leaving a zone" is "sensitive information".

Comment: I wrote a bunch of stuff, then thought against it. The bottom line: you'll be violating federal law.

Comment: I've added a link that explains legitimate use. I don't think this violates any laws so long as you don't sniff the contents of phone conversations. All I want to do is detect the presence of phones and the rate at which they pass through zones.